# What is the best approach to backup Room database?

Tags: android, android-room, database-backups, android-file

Actually I have more than a question. If I uninstall an app, the room database also removed. I debugged and checked using `File(getDatabasePath("MyInfoDatabase.db").absolutePath).exists()` before instantiating a room database. Let's say my app crashed and I uninstalled it and then reinstall the app. So it is not possible to get the old room data.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
    .createFromFile(File("mypath"))
    .build()
```

If I am not wrong, then I can copy and save the database to a directory and get the old databack while reinstalling using the above method. Is this the right approach? In this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916380/room-best-ways-to-create-backups-for-offline-application) `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated now. Should I use `MediaStore` api for database backup? On the other hand [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677497/remove-room-database-on-app-uninstall), it says that room data exists even after uninstalling. Is the room database exists even after uninstalling an app? AFAIK it doesn't exists.